# How do I search for a process by name without using grep?

Tags: command-line, process

In order to search for a process you can use `ps` with `grep`.

For example to search for firefox

```
ps aux | grep firefox
```

How to get the same answer without using `grep`?

Comment: I'm curious why you would want to do this, given that `ps/grep` solution works so well?

Comment: OP just wants a shorter command I'd guess. If there would be a thing like `ps -n <process name>` that would answer his need. `ps -n firefox` is a bit shorter than `ps | grep firefox`. `ps` can already filter on `pid` or processes for a user id, so it's a reasonable question to filter on process name.

Answer (score 102):

The [`pgrep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/pgrep.1) command, and its sibling `pkill`, exists precisely for this purpose:

- `pgrep firefox` will list all processes whose commands match `firefox`
- `pgrep -f firefox` will list all processes whose entire command lines match `firefox`
- `pgrep -x firefox` will list all processes whose commands exactly match `firefox`
- ... and so on.

And naturally, `pgrep` will exclude itself from the match, so none of the `grep` rituals associated with `ps | grep` are needed.

---

The other set of tools for this are the `pidof` and `killall` commands. These aren't as flexible as `pgrep` and `pkill`.

- `pidof firefox` will list processes whose command is `firefox`

Comment: Useful if you have a long command name and/or command line args is `pgrep -f foo` which uses the full process name to match `foo`

Answer (score 36):

```
ps -fC process-name
```

example:

```
ps -fC firefox
```

from `man ps`

```
  -C cmdlist      Select by command name.
                       This selects the processes whose executable name is
                       given in cmdlist.


 -f              Do full-format listing. This option can be combined
                       with many other UNIX-style options to add additional
                       columns. It also causes the command arguments to be
                       printed. When used with -L, the NLWP (number of
                       threads) and LWP (thread ID) columns will be added. See
                       the c option, the format keyword args, and the format
                       keyword comm.
```

Comment: This is the best answer but unfortunately doesn't work on OSX. The BSD `ps -C` flag behaves completely differently - "Change the way the CPU percentage is calculated"

Answer (score 5):

A cool trick

```
$ps -ejH
```

You will get all the processes with names

```
exmple:
1747   568   568 ?        00:00:00   colord
1833  1832  1832 ?        00:00:00   gnome-keyring-d
2263   568   568 ?        00:00:00   udisksd
2311  2311  2311 ?        00:00:00   cupsd
2315  2315  2311 ?        00:00:00     dbus
```

Redirect or so copy the output to a file and then open `nano`,
press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>
and you can search for the name you want.

Answer (score 3):

`top` allows you to search for string when you hit uppercase `L`; the process will be highlighted, and use up and down arrow keys to scroll through list of processes. Similarly,
`htop` command allows highlighting a particular process when  you hit `/`. And `\` will filter all the processes with a particular string in the name.

For those who like awk, here's an awk oneliner: `ps -eF | awk '/process-name/ {print $11}'`
. With `ps -eF` process name is always in 11th column. Alternatively if you do `ps -eF | awk '{print $11}' | sort` you get a sorted list of processes names, sorted alphabetically. Pipe it into `less` command just to view the long list of files easier.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `htop` and then hit F4 to filter the results with a matching user-defined string. You also have a custom search feature available by hitting F3.

Answer (score 2):

If two processes is the problem, you can use *only* grep:

```
grep firefox /proc/*/cmdline
```

Answer (score 2):

If the reason you don't want to use `ps | grep` is because it loses the first line (the column headers), you can do:

```
ps aux | grep 'firefox\|^USER'
```

This is grepping for a line that contains `firefox` or a line that starts with `USER` (the first line of header line on my distro).

Answer (score 0):

I just read this ps alias on the Lennart Poettering Blog. The output is according to the systemd control group parenting:

```
alias psc='ps xawf -eo pid,user,cgroup,args'
```