# Why does ps output show a process even if it is not running?

Tags: process, ps

Why does the `ps` shows a process even if it is not running. While Firefox is running:

```
$ echo $(ps aux | awk  '/firefox/{print $2}')
5964 6041
```

But when Firefox is not running, I tried to run the same command. It showed  a different PID each time.

I tried grepping it:

```
$ ps aux | grep firefox
greenpa+  6056  0.0  0.0  15956   948 pts/11   S+   09:29   0:00 grep --color=auto firefox
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And this is why you shouldn't `grep` or otherwise parse the output of `ps` for matching commands, but use [tools like `pgrep` and `pidof`](https://askubuntu.com/a/612318/158442).

When you run `ps | grep foo`, the `grep foo` process is also listed by `ps` - therefore `grep foo` matches itself along with any other `foo` processes. The exact same thing happens when you do `echo $(ps aux | awk  '/firefox/...)` - the `awk` command matches itself.

Indeed, depending on what output you want from `ps`, you might be better off using `pgrep`'s output with `ps`. For example, the states of all Google Chrome processes in my system:

```
ps -p $(pgrep -d, chrome) -o pid,state
```

`pgrep`'s flexibility in this regard is *very* useful - note how I can specify an output delimiter with `-d`, then use it as PID list argument to `ps`. `pgrep` and `pkill` are also capable of reading from a PID file.

Answer (score 3):

As muru already pointed out grep leaves trace of itself in the ps, however, there is a small workaround for using grep with ps : use double quotes and brackets on the first letter like so  `ps aux | grep "[f]irefox"` (Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74186/85039).