# Not able to kill process

Tags: 16.04, process

When I do `ps -A`, it shows me all running process but not the one which I want to kill.

But the process which I want to kill its shows PID

`ps aux | grep -i resourcemanager` show below output

```
hduser   20155  0.0  0.0  14228   984 pts/5    S+   21:37   0:00 grep --color=auto -i resourcemanager
```

When I kill, `pkill resourcemanager`, and run the same command to check whether resourcemanager is running or not, it shows again with new PID. But never shows up in `ps -A` command output.

Can anyone help, What's wrong happening ..?

Comment: What you're seeing when you do `ps aux | grep -i resourcemanager` is the grep process itself

Comment: @steeldriver, I'm seeing this hduser   20155  0.0  0.0  14228   984 pts/5    S+   21:37   0:00 grep --color=auto -i resourcemanager

Comment: Yes exactly - notice the `grep --color=auto -i resourcemanager` at the end?

Comment: @steeldriver, Yes..What does it says .. ?

Comment: Does the answer here help? [Why does ps output show a process even if it is not running?](https://askubuntu.com/a/613676/178692)

Comment: as an alternative I use this one which might work for you, I use it because vlc leaves icons in the top bar (19.04) even when those vlc's have been closed.                       killall -9 vlc                 yours would be killall -9 resourcemanager    , after sudo apt install killall   if you dont already have it.   is this an answer/solution