# chkrootkit says "grep --color=auto INFECTED," what should I do?

Tags: grep, malware, chkrootkit

I just installed and ran chkrootkit for the first time and when I ran `sudo chkrootkit | grep INFECTED`, it returned `![user] 21342 pts/0  grep --color=auto INFECTED`

I'm a complete novice at this and have no idea what that means or what I should do. Any explanation or help would be very welcome!

My OS is Ubuntu 22.04.1 (Jammy) and as far as I know everything's up to date. I have dual boot with Windows 10 but never use windows, and I have an external monitor that occasionally sends my laptop into a weird ^@^@ errorscreen until I disconnect it, in case that's related somehow??

Thank you for any help!

Comment: `chrootkit` prints some processes' details, but those processes may or may not be problematic. In this case you're seeing the process details of the `grep` command in `sudo chkrootkit | grep INFECTED` itself (if you run `type grep`, you'll see it's an alias to `grep --color=auto`).

Comment: please use `sudo chkrootkit | grep "[I]NFECTED"` to search.  The [ ] make it a regex and makes it not show up in the results. Or use `pgrep` instead of `grep`

Comment: Related: [Why does ps output show a process even if it is not running?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613673/why-does-ps-output-show-a-process-even-if-it-is-not-running)

Answer (score 2):

The tool `grep` simply looks for a specific string in its input. In this case, its input is the output of `sudo chkrootkit` which apparently prints out information about running processes. One of these running processes is the `grep` command you launched. Now, on Ubuntu, `grep` is actually [aliased](https://askubuntu.com/q/17536/85695) to `grep --color=auto` which means that when you run `grep INFECTED`, you are actually running:

```
grep --color=auto INFECTED
```

So what is happening here is that the output of `chkrootkit` includes the running `grep` command and since the `grep` command includes the string `INFECTED` that is being shown in your results. This doesn't mean you have a rootkit or that `grep` is infected or anything else.