# discover if other users are executing the watch command on the machine in which MyOwnCommand is beeing executed

Tags: command-line, scripts

I want to know if there are other users that are running `watch` on the same machine in which command X is being executed. How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I search for a process by name without using grep?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/612315/how-do-i-search-for-a-process-by-name-without-using-grep)

Answer (score 0):

To see what processes are running on a machine, you can use `ps`. This is a command with a huge number of options, so you might want to take a look at `man ps` to learn a little about it.

To check whether anyone is running `watch`, you would do:

```
 $ ps aux | grep -w watch
terdon   15915  0.0  0.0  15912  2676 pts/4    S+   15:58   0:00 watch ls
terdon   16123  0.0  0.0  13948  2264 pts/5    S+   15:58   0:00 grep --color -w watch
```

The `-w` tells `grep` to only match whole words. Otherwise, processes like `watchdog` would also be listed. However, that also returns the grep process itself. To avoid that, you can use `pgrep`:

```
$ pgrep -xl watch
15915 watch
```

The `-x` makes it look for exact matches only and the `-l` makes it also list the process name and not just its PID.

Now, if you want to check for both  `MyOwnCommand` and `watch`, you could do:

```
$ pgrep MyOwnCommand >/dev/null  && pgrep -xl watch
15915 watch
```

The `&&` means that the second `pgrep` will only be run if the first was successful, if `MyOwnCommand` is running. The `>/dev/null` discards the output of the first `pgrep`.