# PID in Ubuntu gnome terminal

Tags: command-line, process, ps

By using `ps aux | grep -i “name of your desired program”` the list of PID's appeared, but I found more PIDs than in the System Monitor.

How is this possible?

I did not find PIDs with `-color =auto` in System Monitor.

Comment: It would help if you would edit your question and include an example of the output you have a question about.  The process count of the applications I have checked using your formula works as expected.

Answer (score 6):

When you run `ps ... | grep ...`, both `ps` and `grep` are started together, and the output of `ps` is fed to `grep` asynchronously. So, by the time `ps` scans the list of processes and prints the output, the `grep` process is also active, and the output of `ps` includes *that* `grep` process as well.

Now, if you do a simple `grep foo`, the output of `ps` will contain `grep foo`, and `grep` will match *that* `foo`:

```
$ ps aux | grep non-existent
muru  19042  0.0  0.0  10760  2224 pts/8    S+   23:56   0:00 grep non-existent
```

Obviously, there's no process named `non-existent`.

Instead of `ps | grep`, [use `pgrep` for cleaner matching](https://askubuntu.com/q/612315/158442):

```
pgrep foo
```

Or `ps` itself, if you know the name of the command:

```
ps -C foo
```

---

Why `grep --color...`? Because Ubuntu defines an alias for `grep` by default:

```
$ alias grep
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
```

---

This is also why you see silly tricks like:

```
ps ... | grep foo | grep -v grep
ps ... | grep '[f]oo'
```

Comment: I'm a bit new to linux,  can i know what foo is? Isn't it just a user defined variable? Or does it have any function.(googled it but not yet found a google explanation).

Comment: @user648595 it's anything you want it to be: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar